# Custom Header through curl request are not received by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl

I am making an api. I am testing it with curl
Url - http://example.com/api/sessions.json

My request -

`curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"-H "EMAIL:prashant@example.com" -d "" http://example.com/api/sessions.json`

When access `request.headers` from rails in the create of Api::SessionsController, i found no header with the name "EMAIL".

I also tried added 'X-' before any header value, but no success. Please if somebody answer to this question.

Comment: Can you include the output of request.headers?

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your problem:

```
"Content-Type: application/json"-H "EMAIL:prashant@example.com"
                               ^^
```

There is no space between the previous header and the `-H`. So its assuming next to it as url and you are getting nothing!